# Scroll to the Top of Browser on back history after DOM have been changed. In angular and angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-router

I'm not sure wherever is it bug or feature of **angular**, **angular-ui-router** or Chrome. But I've got this bug on Chrome v41 + OSX or Win7.

It will be better to see example on planker
http://plnkr.co/HNlXhH

And use steps to reproduce it:

- page1: click page2 link"
- page2: push back on browser
- page1: do nothing just look
- page1: list will apper in 1 sec
- page1: we will scroll by code to the (0, 500)
- page1: lazy element will be added in 2 sec
- page1: accidently page will scroll to the top right after lazy element

but also you can check them here (as you can see nothing special):

```
//main.js

var app = angular.module('MainApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
    $stateProvider
        .state('page1', {
            url: '/page1',
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
        })
        .state('page2', {
            url: '/page2',
            templateUrl: 'page2.html'
        })
});

app.controller('Page1Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        $timeout(function() {
            $window.scrollTo(0, 800);
        });
    }, 1000);
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.lazy = true;
    }, 2000);
});
```